# ModBus holding register convert to string

Tags: c#, modbus, kepserverex

I've a device connected via ModBus TCP/IP.

I read data in c# and check via KepServerEx. If I compare the raw int value I get same result but when I try to convert into string no.

I read 8 register with value

12544,50,0,0,0,0,0,0

KepSever show me this string -> 1

C# conversion ->  (with EasyModBus) ATALA or other value but not 1

I try to "play" with ASCII table to find a path for get only a string with "1" like KepServerEX... no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modbus does not define how a character string is transmitted, it only defines the transmission of 16-bit words and bits.

So EasyModBus may show one string and another modbus client may show another, it all depends on the programmer who wrote the code, one thought he had to do the conversion one way and another did it differently, since there is no standard.

Comment: Ok but way the register raw value is the same but the string coversion no?

Comment: Yes, mainly due to use a different Endianness

Comment: Ok but I try some permutations of a Endiannes. Any idea to obtain "1" from 12544,50,0,0,0,0,0?

Comment: decimal 12555, 50 in hex can be 3100, 0032 or 0031, 3200. ASCII 31 is "1" and ASCII "32" is  "2" . In first case can be converted to "1" and the rest of the string probably is ignored due a null character is found